# Micro-Manager-1.4: ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythonpath

So I've got this kind of error while trying to handle Micro-Manager-1.4 with Python 3 (3.6)
(about MM here https://micro-manager.org/wiki/Using_the_Micro-Manager_python_library)

```
    runfile('D:/Programmes/MITHIC/bastien/pymithic/mithic_micro_manager.py', wdir='D:/Programmes/MITHIC/bastien/pymithic')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-9d38937258ec>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Programmes/MITHIC/bastien/pymithic/mithic_micro_manager.py', wdir='D:/Programmes/MITHIC/bastien/pymithic')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/Programmes/MITHIC/bastien/pymithic/mithic_micro_manager.py", line 22, in <module>
    import MMCorePy

  File "C:\Program Files\Micro-Manager-1.4\MMCorePy.py", line 25, in <module>
    _MMCorePy = swig_import_helper()

  File "C:\Program Files\Micro-Manager-1.4\MMCorePy.py", line 21, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_MMCorePy', fp, pathname, description)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)

ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

In English, the procedure cannot be found here.

However, I proceeded as explained on the MM website and my PYTHONPATH contains "C:\Program Files\Micro-Manager-1.4".

Do I have to consider re-installing ? I'm working on a non-admin computer.

Find below my code,

```
import os
import sys
MM_PATH = os.path.join('C:', os.path.sep, 'Program Files',
'Micro-Manager-1.4')
sys.path.append(MM_PATH)
os.environ['PATH'] = MM_PATH + ';' + os.environ['PATH']

import MMCorePy
```

I've checked a few online, but people with this issue had sometimes just forgot the path or something equivalent... or I misunderstood something ?

Enjoy your day !

Answer (score 0):

MMCore.Py as distributed with Micro-Manager is build for Python 2.7, not 3. This is most likely the source for the errors you encounter.  Work is underway to distribute a Python 3-compatible version.  It is also possible to build your own MMCore.py for Python 3.